# Phonegap Network State

Tags: cordova

I am trying to check for the network state in my phonegap application (using phonegap 2.2.0) however im being displayed with an alert saying Conection type: undefined.  And when I do a console.log it returns 0.

I am using the code as it is provided by phonegap and calling it after the onDeviceReady.  Here is the code im using:

```
function checkConnection() {
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

var states = {};
states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);

}
```

Did anyone ever encounter this issue or has any ideas how to go around it?  At the moment I am using a WiFi connection, and even on a 3G connection it returns the same.

Comment: What platform are you testing this on?

Comment: What exactly are you logging? if `networkState` is 0, then NetworkStatus plugin may be absent.

Comment: @NickRoth  I am testing on Android (Target SDK 16)

Comment: @keune I was logging networkState.  The networkStatus plugin is included in my config.xml though..

Comment: where in your application are you using this function? can you show more code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check this steps:

- First check permissions. Make sure you have added

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  ```

  in your AndroidManifest.xml
- Second check correct plugin configuration. If you were using an old Phonegap tutorial (Pre 1.6 version) with new Phonegap/Cordova framework you should change res/xml/plugins.xml from:

  ```
  <plugin name="Network Status" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
  ```

  to be:

  ```
  <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
  ```
- Last version of Phonegap/Cordoca has a bug with:

  ```
   navigator.connection.type
  ```

  Change it to:

  ```
  navigator.network.connection.type.
  ```

  You could also use older 2.1 version or wait for the version 2.3
- Long shoot , have you used deviceready event before executing function ***checkConnecting()***?
- Worst case scenario change your code and try it like this:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

      var deviceInfo = function(){
        alert(navigator.network.connection.type);
      }

      function init(){
          document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceInfo, true);
      }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init();">

    </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: changing navigator.connection.type to navigator.network.connection.type did the trick!  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it is a bug in 2.2 that is fixed in 2.3.

Comment: I just updated answer with latest update from plugin.cordova.io site